# How change only one parameter in file

Tags: linux, shell, parameters, sed

I have one problem need help. 
I'm writting a script to change parameter in file example

```
global
  maxconn 4096
  pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
  daemon

defaults
  mode http
  retries 3
  maxconn 2000
```

i want to change maxconn in global to 10000 and keep maxconn in defaults is 2000 but when i change maxconn in global by command sed, maxconn in defaults also changed. please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else just use awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/^global/{ sub(/maxconn[^\n]+/,"maxconn 10000") }1' file
global
  maxconn 10000
  pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
  daemon

defaults
  mode http
  retries 3
  maxconn 2000
```

To write the output of a command (awk or whatever) back to the original file:

```
command file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

"tmp" is just some tmp file named whatever and wherever you please, `/usr/tmp/tmp$$` for example.

So for this particular command you could do:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/^global/{ sub(/maxconn[^\n]+/,"maxconn 10000") }1' file > /usr/tmp/tmp$$ && mv /usr/tmp/tmp$$ file
```

Comment: +1, and how about adding a `space` or `\s` to make `maxconn\s[^\n]+`, so that it could distinguish `maxconn xxx` and `maxconn2 xxx`?

Comment: It's possible, the OP can decide if they want to do that. I wouldn't use `\s` though as that's non-portable, I'd use `[[:blank:]]`. (S)he might also want to consider accommodating `newmaxconn` or similar - we'll see if the OP provides any other input to be considered.

Comment: yes `[[:blank:]]` is better! True master won't neglect even a tiny thing..!

Comment: I'm just stupid enough to make all the mistakes but not quite stupid enough not to learn from them :-). I've been using sed for 30+ years and awk for about 20 so I've had my share of disasters!

Comment: 30 years ago, I had no idea what does a "computer" look like, I thought it would be the 2nd name of a "calculator" .. and you had started using `sed`....

Comment: oh thankyou for answer but when i use your command it view maxconn in global is 10000 but i vi file is maxconn not change

Comment: I just updated my answer with info on how to update the original file.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Wrong number of parameters"
    exit
fi

awk -v new_value=$1 '{
    if ($2 == "")
            global = ($1 == "global");

    if ($1 == "maxconn" && global) {
            printf "  maxconn %s\n", new_value;
    } else {
            print $0;
    }
}'
```

To run execute:

```
./change.sh 10000 < conf.txt
```

I am assuming that the above script is named change.sh and your input is saved in conf.txt.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^global/{:a;n;s/^(\s*maxconn ).*/\110000/;Ta}' file
```

This looks for a line beginning `global` then prints that line and next and the next etc until the current line contains `maxconn` when it substitutes the new value and the loop is broken.

Comment: @user2709443 it's not, the first `1` is actually `\1` and is a backreference to the `   maxconn ` string.